# Looking for an OSD supporting align attribute, multiple span or div elements, multiple columns

Tags: user-interface, gnome, xlib, renderer, pango

Please let me know if there is an OSD **on-screen-display program** or **techinque** for Xorg/Linux platform which can render XML in a much richer way than pango, at least support align attribute, and multiple span or div elements, so it can display multiple columns.

e.g. [chipmunkav osd](http://www.chipmunkav.com/help/osd.htm)

What i have checked so far :

- **gnome-osd-client** renders XML but gnome-osd-client provide very simple XML pango
- **osd_cat** but it do not take any XML.
- **navit** have some kind of XML for OSM data which uses osd, but hardly understandable.

If no such *osd program* exist than please let me know

- HTML renderer with different backends support that can programmed to display using OSD.
- Relavent source from other existing package (like navit,) that is using osd in backend, could be used to render this kind of XML.

My problem is that i actually use pango but it is not flexible enough to fit me needs with displaying XML in multi-column.

Comment: Sharad, Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.